# Why I can't import just numpy module with PythonKit in swift?

Tags: python, swift, xcode, import

I am trying to import module (any kind of module just to testing this function) with this sample code in a FinderSync file in my swift project:
let sys = Python.import("sys")
let maybeModule = Python.import("prova")
print(maybeModule)
I have also write "import PythonKit" ath the top of the file.
When I try to execute the script I have this error:

PythonKit/Python.swift:706: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Python exception: No module named 'prova'
2023-07-28 19:17:37.181537+0200 FinderExt[3603:103784] PythonKit/Python.swift:706: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Python exception: No module named 'prova'

My Xcode version is: 14.3.1
My swift version is: 5.8.1

Please, I need an help!